# Why did the Sharpes choose this approach for Edith?

Tags: plot-explanation, crimson-peak

In [Crimson Peak](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2554274/), why do Lucille and Thomas Sharpe try to kill Edith with poison instead of simply using a knife? In the last scenes we see that Lucille threatens Edith with a knife to sign the paper. Why didn't she and her brother/lover do it already?

Answer (score 1):

I believe they needed Edith’s signature to complete the transfer of Edith’s estate.  Lacking e-signatures bring absolutely sure of proper signatures was paramount.  Account would be in Thomas’s and Edith’s name and he could draw on the account.